# Grails - How to inject bean defined in resources.groovy in integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have 1 bean defined in resources.groovy

```
cachedbean(serviceImpl) {
  }
```

In service I am using it this way

```
    MyService{

      static transactional = false
      def cachedbean

        myMeth(){
         cachedbean.get("cacheKey")
      }
   }
```

This works fine but when I try to test it with integration test, I get `nullpointer` exception on '`get`'
cachedbean.`get`("cacheKey").

How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "new"-ing up the service instance, if you let Grails auto wire the service bean into your integration test class it should be auto wired.

```
class MyServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    def myService
    void testSomething () {
        // myService should already be wired up
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. It's unclear if you did or not based on your sample code, but you need to fully-qualify out the package and class name for "serviceImpl" in your `resources.groovy` unless you explicitly import the package.
2. You may need to add inside the scope of your declaration in `resources.groovy` the line `bean.autowire = "byName"`

Comment: 1) I added fully-qualified name for serviceImpl. 2) it's working in the code but failing for integration test only. So will it affect BY adding it explicitly?

Comment: It shouldn't negatively affect anything by adding `bean.autowire = "byName"`, no. I just had a thought, though: are you referencing this service second-hand? Meaning, is your test for another service which is calling this one? If so, spring isn't quite smart enough to know to inject this service and you may need your test to manually assign a value to `cachedBean` after all.

Comment: No. I am calling this service method directly.

Comment: How are you getting a reference to `MyService` in your test?

Comment: Fully qualifying the class name in resourcs.groovy must not be the problem as the OP stated that the wiring works in the running app and Grails uses autowire by name by default so there is no reason to specify that here (again, the wiring works in the running app).

Comment: @kevinmershon I am creating object using new.